# C# Activex Cross Platform

Tags: c#, browser, activex

I created a simple .NET COM activex and it would be great if it could be run on different browser such as Chrome, Mozilla and so on, not on IE only.

Is it possible? Is there some work around to execute an activex on other browser?

Comment: You could wrap it into an executable application that would run under windows. Simply offer it as a download option.

Comment: ActiveX is a microsoft product, that has the purpose of making you think it is an open web based thing, while at the same time trapping you in a closed thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short no. Chrome, FireFox etc do not support activex natively. There is some extensions to FireFox which will allow it.  If you force people to install these extensions to run your software you will probably open a maintenance can of worms. In short activex is great for a corporate network where u can force the usage of IE.

Comment: I have developed some activex several years ago and we had some limited success with it. The problem was the errors that came from the Mozilla browsers with the ActiveX plugin. We spend more time trying to fix things on the activeX than actually improving it. Using AJAX,XHTML and CSS gave us the same functionality but with less issues.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible to run ActiveX on other browsers.
Another possiblilty is to use applets